# After upgrading saxon-he-10.5 JAR, facing issue in the transformation

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have two XSL file, one XSL importing another one ,
Not getting any value in the variable data. The variable data I am using below to get the attributes. Since the data is empty. Not getting values from it. is there anything wrong in this line <xsl:variable name="data" select="$header/sections/code[@key=$key]"/>

XSL 1 : Veichle.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="Motor.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:param name="key" select="'vita'"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

XSL 2: Motor.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:f1="urn:hl7-org:v3"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3"
  xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xpath-default-namespace="http://hl7.org/fhir"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:lookup="http://lookup.data"
  xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID" exclude-result-prefixes="fn lookup uuid sdtc cda xsl xsi f1">
    <xsl:import href="section.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:param name="key" select="'results'"/>
    <xsl:param name="mostRecent" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="header">
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Yes, xpath-default-namespace is there in <xsl:transform></xsl:transform>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the namespace issue pointed out in the comment, i.e. to set `xpath-default-namespace="http://hl7.org/fhir"` where you want to select elements from that namespace, the other error in your code is in the section `$header/sections/code/[@key=$key]` where you probably want `$header/sections/code[@key=$key]`, i.e. a boolean predicate on the last step for the `code` elements.

If you really upgraded from XSLT 1 or 2 to Saxon 10, then I would think for older processors the expression you have should have given you an error and in XSLT 3 it would create a sequence of arrays with a boolean value.

Comment: My bad, the original code is <xsl:variable name="data" select="$header/sections/code[@key=$key]"/>. While adding the question here it got added.

Comment: @Sumit, perhaps add some more precise information on which result you want, which version of which XSLT processor you used earlier. With `<xsl:param name="key" select="'results'"/>` and the expression `$header/sections/code[@key=$key]` I don't see how `code key="engine"` or `code key="exterior"` could be selected.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 we are using. The same code works fine with Saxon HE 9.x . When I am running this locally or through command prompt as the suggestion by Saxonica the trensformation works fine. But one I run this on a server(Jboss) I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `$header/sections/code/[@key=$key]` wasn't valid in XPath 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0. In XPath 3.1 it has a meaning (it returns an array), but it's not the meaning you think it has. As Martin explains, you probably intended `$header/sections/code[@key=$key]`, but I don't know why your previous XSLT processor didn't flag an error.

Comment: Yes the original code having  $header/sections/code[@key=$key], I have added wrongly here

Comment: Well as far as I can see the `$data` variable isn't used in your transformation, so there is still something you're not telling us. We can't solve the problem on incomplete information.

Comment: Earlier I had given the code where the root cause was, I have added the piece of code where we are trying to get an element from the variable data.

Comment: You now need to fix the namespace issues identified by Martin Honnen.